# Apache Cordova Windows Phone 8 App ajax call request status returns 0

Tags: apache, frameworks, cordova

I have developed an app using Apache Cordova Windows Phone 8 framework.I am working on emulator.

My first page makes an ajax call to a WCF service to show list of employees depending upon user input.I have shown data returned by Ajax call on my page.Everything works fine till this.

The problem starts when I click on Back button of the emulator. Back button takes me to start of the emulator where we can see all the app icons.

When I click on my app icon it opens index.html which is my main page.When I enter my search criteria and press search button, ajax call returns request status 0.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening and not finding anything useful in internet search. My ajax call is this

```
    // Require cross-site scripting so enable it here (calling different website)
    $.support.cors = true;

    var jsonData = { 'searchCriteria': 'Raj'};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://hqit116/EmployeeWCFService/EmployeeWCFServices.svc/GetEmployeeData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        processData: true,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: OnFailure
    });
```

Can someone please help me with this. This is really stopping me progress with my next bit of work.